# how to populate a database?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with a single table, that includes an autoincrement ID, a string and two numbers. I want to populate this database with many strings, coming from a text file, with all numbers initially reset to 0.

Is there a way to do it quickly? I thought of creating a script that generates many INSERT statements, but that seems somewhat primitive and slow. Especially since mysql is on remote site.

Comment: Can you please post sample line of text file which you want to import?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - use `LOAD DATA INFILE` [docs are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) Example :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'csvfile'
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES
(cola, colb, colc)
SET cold = 0,
cole = 0;
```

Notice the `set` line - here is where you set a default value.

Depending on your field separator change the line `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

Comment: thanks! when I try to do that, I get: LOAD DATA INFILE 'bundles/PACKAGE1.TXT' INTO TABLE textrating FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 0 LINES (textline);
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user username ... etc  -- I know my privileges are set so that I can add as much data as I want. Is there a need to set up special privileges for LOAD DATA INFILE? I will note that secure_file_priv is NULL here, and that I am trying to load data from a local file to a remote server.

Comment: I will also note that "SHOW GRANTS" says that I have all privileges.

Comment: In the mysql.user table make sure FILE_PRIV = 'Y' for your user

Comment: argh... I don't have access to this table.

Comment: By default someone with root access to the db should be able to check/add this permission for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to server's file system, you can utilize [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

If you don't want to fight with syntax, easiest way (if on windows) is to use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php)

It has friendly wizard for this purpose.

Maybe I can help you with right syntax, if you post sample line from text file.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers only respond to half of your question. For the other half (zeroing numeric columns):

**Either:**

1. Set the default value of your number columns to `0`,
2. In your text file, simply delete the numeric values,
3. This will cause the field to be read by LOAD INFILE as null, and the defauly value will be assigned, which you have set to 0.

**Or:**

1. Once you have your data in the table, issue a MySQL command to zero the fields, like

   `UPDATE table SET first_numeric_column_name  = 0, second_numeric_column_name = 0 WHERE 1;`

And to sum everything up, use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Data-Back-Up/Import-Data/How-to-use-LOAD-DATA-INFILE-statement).

Comment: Thanks @Martin, you beat me to it!

Comment: im actually that anal about the highlighting its annoying me it wraps to a new line !!!!! perhaps i need some DayQuil !!! :-)

Comment: @ManseUK Perhaps that's the issue. I usually wrap my `code` in backticks, but I was sure I clicked the code button this time. Perhaps single-line backtick-wrapped code doesn't get a horizontal scroller?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [SB Data Generator](https://soft-builder.com/sb-data-generator/) by Softbuilder (which I work for), download and install the free trial.

First, create a connection to your MySQL database then go to **“Tools -> Virtual Data”** and import your test data (the file must be in CSV format).

After importing the test data, you will be able to preview them and query them in the same window without inserting them into the database.

Now, if you want to insert test data into your database, go to **“Tools -> Data Generation”** and select "generate data from virtual data".

[SB data generator from Softbuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cITF6.png)